# Topmost bar with battery and network not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout

The topmost bar that has battery and network is coming as plain white bar.
Please help in fixing this.
Thanks

It's coming like this

[image: It is coming like this]

It should be like this

[image: It should be like this]

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search products.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check above you added  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" to your appbarlayout remove this and check

Comment: Post your `v21/styles.xml` file.

Comment: btw that top most bar is called as `StatusBar`

Comment: @AnkushBist didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix that has worked for me is to switch to `CoordinatorLayout`. ie

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <!-- your contents here -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Move your layout contents inside the `CoordinatorLayout`. Also `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is necessary, couldn't get it work without `fitSystemWindows` set to true. Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Please can you also explain what was wrong in using Linear Layout and what worked for Coordinator Layout

Comment: coordinate_layout is a parent layout for these appBarLayout and Toolbar with advance features. CoordinateLayout is introduced in material design and further api versions. Better to study yourself about this.